# Encryption and decryption using rotating letters

Tags: python

In my program I am supposed to be able to encrypt and decrypt a sentence by rotating letters. The encryption side of my code works but the decryption side does not. When I asked my teacher for help he said something was wrong with `if charValue > 90` in the second half of my code. He said that I must use a different value for a lower range. Anyone might know what that is?

```
phrase = input("Please enter a phrase: ")
rotationAmount = int(input("Enter the rotation amount (1 - 25): "))
enc0rDecStr = int(input("Enter 1 for encryption or 2 for decryption: "))
phrase = phrase.upper()
if enc0rDecStr == 1:
    encryptedPhrase = ""
    for i in range(0, len(phrase)):
        charValue = ord(phrase[i])
        if charValue != 32:
            charValue += rotationAmount
            if charValue > 90:
                charValue -= 26
        encryptedPhrase += chr(charValue)
    print("The original phrase is: ", phrase)
    print("The encrypted phrase is: ", encryptedPhrase)
if enc0rDecStr == 2:
    decryptedPhrase = ""
    for i in range(0, len(phrase)):
        charValue = ord(phrase[i])
        if charValue != 32:
            charValue -= rotationAmount
            if charValue > 90:
                charValue += 26
            decryptedPhrase += chr(charValue)
        print("The original phrase is: ", phrase)
        print("The decrypted phrase is: ", decryptedPhrase)
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the `charValue`s you get at that point?  That's your first debugging hint.  Please post a full [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE) -- self-contained.  Hard-code some input for a test.  Also trace significant values.

Comment: Please don't edit out part of the code; it is better to post it as a whole for context. When you subtract `rotationAmount` from `charValue` it can go below some value; not above. You must replace `if charValue > 90:` with `if charValue < [something]:`. That `[something]` is yours to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

In `decrypt` function, you have to do every process of `encrypt` in reverse order. Thus, charValue += 26 should be coming before `if charValue > 90` as follows:

```
def encrypt(phrase, rotationAmount):
    encryptedPhrase = ""
    for p in phrase:
        charValue = ord(p)
        if charValue != 32:
            charValue += rotationAmount
            if charValue > 90:
                charValue -= 26
        encryptedPhrase += chr(charValue)
    print("The original phrase is: ", phrase)
    print("The encrypted phrase is: ", encryptedPhrase)
    return encryptedPhrase

def decrypt(encrypted, rotationAmount):
    decryptedPhrase = ""
    for p in encrypted:
        charValue = ord(p)
        if charValue != 32:
            charValue -= rotationAmount
            charValue += 26
            if charValue > 90:
                charValue -= 26
        decryptedPhrase += chr(charValue)
    print("The original phrase is: ", encrypted)
    print("The decrypted phrase is: ", decryptedPhrase)
    return decryptedPhrase
```

Result:

```
The original phrase is:  YOUR PHRASE IS HERE
The encrypted phrase is:  IYEB ZRBKCO SC ROBO
The original phrase is:  IYEB ZRBKCO SC ROBO
The decrypted phrase is:  YOUR PHRASE IS HERE
```